# Web Push API Chrome, returning "Unauthorized Registration"

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

I've been doing a [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/#download_the_sample_code) on how to send web push notifications on Chrome using web-push node module.

The thing is, the tutorial also provides a [companion server app](https://web-push-codelab.appspot.com/) that you are supposed to use in order to test sending push notifications from a server to the client.

But, in both the companion app and even when using web-push cli on my local machine, when trying to send a notification I am getting a "**Unauthorized Registration**" error.
Can't find anything online about this error - what am I doing wrong/ missing?

```
$ web-push send-notification --endpoint=https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/<<endpoint-key>>
Error sending push message:
{ [WebPushError: Received unexpected response code]
  name: 'WebPushError',
  message: 'Received unexpected response code',
  statusCode: 400,
  headers:
   { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     date: 'Fri, 25 Nov 2016 08:54:08 GMT',
     expires: 'Fri, 25 Nov 2016 08:54:08 GMT',
     'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
     server: 'GSE',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"',
     'accept-ranges': 'none',
     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
     connection: 'close' },
  body: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>UnauthorizedRegistration</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>UnauthorizedRegistration</H1>\n<H2>Error 400</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n' }
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/emretekince/fcm-web-push

Comment: The truth for me appeared to be: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42023959/813000

Answer (score 1):

Have you used any HTTP server to test the code in that tutorial? Further, DNS should be **localhost** or **https://** site. If you are running the HTTP server under some port, better to have 5 digit client side port. Here is linked my project [browser push](https://lahiiru.github.io/browser-push)

Answer (score 0):

There's a report of this in the [web-push library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) issue tracker: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push/issues/254.

Can you try resetting your clock, like the reporters in that issue did?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the GH issue! Unfortunately, resetting the clock doesn't really help

Answer (score 0):

Check the field *gcm_sender_id* in your **manifest.json** file if it matches exactly with the *gcm_sender_id* in your google account. I faced a similar problem before and this was the solution to my problem.